# How do I change (upgrade) my Elastic Beanstalk instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

My current Elastic Beanstalk environment is using the "t2.micro" instance. Recently, my website is getting a lot of traffic and it is not been able to handle CRON jobs. The instance is getting overloaded with high memory usage.

I want to change my instance to better RAM (at least 4GB). I can't find the option to change the instance type in Elastic Beanstalk settings.

Can you please guide me on how to upgrade the instance without any downtime? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html) tells you how to do this.

1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console, and in the Regions list, select your AWS Region.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Environments.
3. Choose Create a new environment to start creating your environment.
4. On the wizard's main page, before choosing Create environment, choose Configure more options.
5. In the Instances configuration category, choose Edit. Make changes to settings in this category, and then choose Apply. For setting descriptions, see the section Instances category settings on this page.
6. In the Capacity configuration category, choose Edit. Make changes to settings in this category, and then choose Continue. For setting descriptions, see the section Capacity category settings on this page.